# Rails, How to send mails to multiple users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, redmine

I am working on a Redmine plugin and trying to senf email to multiple users via loop, but the problem is that when I used it, it was sending email only to last user.
Have put the code for the same.
Please help.

```
  def leave_request(receivers)
    receivers.each do |receiver|
        test = User.find_by_id(receiver)
        mail(to: test.mail, subject: 'Welcome to ABC Leave application module')
    end
  end
```

Comment: why do you think that only last user is sent email? Have you check log file? maybe add gem `mailcatcher` to test sending emails locally

Comment: have debugged it manually and yes have checked the logs also

Comment: it is worth to expose us code which invokes leave_request function and the way recievers variable is forming

Comment: EmployeeLeaveMailer.leave_request(@teamleads_id).deliver
and @teamleads_id contains id, and is a array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `leave_request` is your mailer method. You can only send one e-mail with one call of `deliver`. You can either move your logic out of the mailer, use `:cc`, or add all recipients to the `:to` field.